# What is the inference behind the momentum variable and the Kinetic energy for a weakly non-linear inverse problems in the HMC method?

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo, inverse-problem

We generate an auxiliary momentum variable in the HMC method to provide gradient for the propagation of trajectory (m, p) (model or position, momentum) in the phase space.

If we look into Newton's method, where misfit function is square of the L2 norm of the difference between the synthetic and observed data, we get the model perturbation vector equal to the product of the inverse of the Hessian and gradient of the misfit function (Virieux et al., 2009). Similarly, when solving Hamilton's equation for the position (model) and momentum update in HMC method, we get the derivative of position with respect to time as equal to the product of the inverse of mass-matrix and momentum. Further solving the combined form of Hamilton's equation, we can estimate the mass matrix to be equal to the Hessian of the misfit function for the linear and weakly non-linear inverse problems as shown in Fitchner et al., 2018.

From this fact, could we interpret that the momentum variable is analogous to the gradient of the misfit function? If yes, then what would be the inference behind choosing the Kinetic energy, which is the Gaussian distribution with zero mean and covariance equal to the mass matrix for the linear and weakly non-linear inverse problems.